# Jenkins instance goes offline automatically once every 2 weeks

Tags: jenkins

Once in 2 weeks, Jenkins seems to be going offline automatically. It doesn't come back automatically. The jenkins process is still running though. So, I have to kill the existing jenkins process and manually bring it up.

I have included the log below. I have checked for any scheduled jobs or the plugins that might be causing the shutdown. But I don't have any clue. Has anybody seen this issue before? Can somebody kindly shed some light here or provide any clues to help my identify the root cause.

stopScavenging
INFO: node0 Stopped scavenging
Apr 20, 2019 2:44:18 AM jenkins.model.Jenkins cleanUp
INFO: Stopping Jenkins
Apr 20, 2019 2:44:18 AM jenkins.model.Jenkins$18 onAttained
INFO: Started termination
Apr 20, 2019 2:44:18 AM jenkins.model.Jenkins$18 onAttained
INFO: Completed termination
Apr 20, 2019 2:44:18 AM jenkins.model.Jenkins _cleanUpDisconnectComputers
INFO: Starting node disconnection
Apr 20, 2019 2:44:19 AM jenkins.model.Jenkins _cleanUpShutdownPluginManager
INFO: Stopping plugin manager
Apr 20, 2019 2:44:19 AM jenkins.model.Jenkins _cleanUpPersistQueue
INFO: Persisting build queue
Apr 20, 2019 2:44:19 AM jenkins.model.Jenkins _cleanUpAwaitDisconnects
INFO: Waiting for node disconnection completion
Apr 20, 2019 2:44:19 AM jenkins.model.Jenkins cleanUp
INFO: Jenkins stopped
Apr 20, 2019 2:44:20 AM org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler doStop
INFO: Stopped w.@38145825{Jenkins v2.164.1,/,null,UNAVAILABLE}{/data/jenkins_home/war}
Apr 20, 2019 2:44:20 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Jetty shutdown successfully
Apr 20, 2019 2:44:20 AM winstone.Logger logInternal
INFO: Control thread shutdown successfully

By the way, here is the jenkins process that runs on the Linux server

/data/java/jdk1.8.0_181/bin/java -DJENKINS_HOME=/data/jenkins_home -jar /data/jenkins/jenkins.war --controlPort=8001

Regards,
Sam

Comment: You might consider adding some more details for clarity -
Jenkins version?
Linux distro/version?
Other specific troubleshooting steps you've tried.

Give as much detail as you can for others to help you.

Comment: jenkins version is v2.164.1.

Comment: Linux distro is 3.10.0-957.1.3.el7.x86_64. I went through the logs generated at the time of shutdown. But it doesn't indicate any issue. Checked if there is any thinbackup job scheduled that could be causing this auto shutdown, but didn't see any. At this point, I am clueless.